# Understanding JavaScript anonymous vs. named functions in object literals

Tags: javascript, jquery, anonymous-function

Why does the "complete" callback for the third animation happen first, before any animations have started?

Script:

```
$( "#animate" ).delay(2000).animate(
    { "width":    "500px" },
    { "duration": 3000,
      "complete": function(){ $( "#animate" ).append( "1st<br />" ); }}
)
.delay(1000).animate(
    { "width":    "200px" },
    { "duration": 3000,
      "complete": function(){ complete( "2nd" ); }}
)
.delay(1000).animate(
    { "width":    "500px" },
    { "duration": 3000,
      "complete": complete( "3rd" ) }
);

function complete( ordinal ){
    $( "#animate" ).append( ordinal + "<br />" );
};
```

HTML:

```
<div id="animate" />
```

CSS:

```
#animate
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 200px;
    width:  200px;
}
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nQftS/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The callback expects a function. You, however, do not pass a function. You *call* a function.

```
  "complete": complete( "3rd" )
```

which appends things as defined within that function. It then returns nothing, so it evaluates to:

```
  "complete": undefined
```

Note that passing a function works without parentheses. E.g.

```
  "complete": complete
```

or

```
  "complete": function() { ... } // this is also a function
```

Comment: This was very clear. It made me realize the parens make the call, like the pattern: `(function(){...})();`. Knowing that it returned `undefined`, and that it is expecting a function declaration instead, lead me to a rewrite of `complete()` that works and still maintains the concise readability of `"complete": complete( "3rd" )`. New function: `function complete( ordinal ){ return function(){ ... }; };`.

Answer (score 5):

```
"complete": complete( "3rd" )
```

This line will execute the `complete` function, passing in a parameter of "3rd" and then set the returned value of that function to "complete".

```
"complete": function(){ complete( "2nd" ); }
```

This line will instead set "complete" to a function, which, when called, will execute the `complete` function, passing a parameter of "2nd".

Answer (score 0):

On your last part, wrap it in a function:

```
.delay(1000).animate( 
    { "width":    "500px" }, 
    { "duration": 3000,
      "complete": function(){complete( "3rd" ) }
    }
);
```

If you don't do this then the function gets called immediately, which is **not** what you wanted.